# auto relate a foreign Key Field to a pk object django

Tags: django, forms, django-views

I have two models:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Addimg(models.Model):

    post = models.ForeignKey('Post')
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='%Y/%m/%d')
```

Now I have a view for Addimg model to append Images to a Post:

```
def addimg(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = AddimgForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            addimg = form.save(commit=False)
            addimg.image = request.FILES['image']
            addimg.save()
            return redirect('blog.views.list')
    else:
        form = AddimgForm()
    return render(request, 'blog/edit.html', {'form': form})
```

Working so far of course the image field in my form is a choice field where i select the Post where i want my image to be related to. What I want: I ve a detail view of every post in there is a button "add image" I wonder if it would be possible to request the pk of my current post and auto relate my Addimg model to this pk without a field in its form. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok just braught it to work with only django:

views.py

```
def addimg(request, pk):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = AddimgForm(request.POST, request.FILES, initial={'post':post})
        if form.is_valid():
            addimg = form.save(commit=False)
            addimg.image = request.FILES['image']
            addimg.save()
            return redirect('blog.views.list')
    else:
        form = AddimgForm(initial={'post':post})
    return render(request, 'blog/appendimg.html', {'form': form })
```

forms.py

```
class AddimgForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta: 
        model = Addimg 
        fields = ('post', 'image',)
        widgets = {'post': forms.HiddenInput()}
```

template form:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" class="post-form">{% csrf_token %}
    {% for hidden in form.hidden_fields %}
    {{hidden}}
    {% endfor %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <p><button type="submit" >Save</button></p>
</form>
```

Don't know if it's a recommended way cause i'm a beginner but seams to work fine. Hope it maybe helps someone other

Answer (score 0):

A possible approach is to make the post selection field hidden in your template and then list all the posts along with "Add image" buttons for each one. Then, you would have a JS function called by clicking the buttons that would update the hidden field to select the post corresponding to the clicked button. Clicking the button could also submit the form using JS, if that's the UX you're after.